# Host a subdomain in Azure DNS using webs.com

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

My company created a web site using webs.com and, to host it, we are using a domain directly registered in webs.com (here I will call it contoso.com). Now I would like to create a subdomain (e.g. subdomain.contoso.com) to access a website hosted in Azure created for a new service offered by my company.

To do this I followed the official guide in the Azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns. Briefly:

- I created a DNS zone in Azure called subdomain.contoso.com;
- I retrievd the list of four name servers;
- I added all the four servers in webs.com (doing this I noticed that there was other two server already registered in webs.com but I don't deleted them);
- I tried to verify if the delegation works...

The problem is that the delegation verification failed (I can't access in to subdomain.contoso.com via the browser and nslookup returns "non-existent domain").

For this reason I tried to add two records in the Azure DNS zone:

- An A record with the VM IP address;
- A CNAME record for the www.test.contoso.com subdomain;

After that, I waited for hours but nothing changed...

Comment: Do you have finished [delegate a domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns#delegate-the-domain) to Azure DNS? `In the registrar's DNS management page, edit the NS records and replace the NS records with the Azure DNS name servers.` Or could you show how you configure it ?

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks for your reply. Yes, I added the 4 name servers in webs.com. I do not know if it is relevant or not but two other servers have already been registered and I have not deleted them in order not to create disruptions.

Comment: You can verify the delegation via the command `nslookup -type=SOA contoso.com` on your machine. What's the result?

Comment: It works (I'll edit the post with the full result). The domain contoso.com is used to access the main web site created directly with webs.com. Briefly I'm working to publish a new service hosted in Azure.

Comment: I already added an A and CNAME record in my Azure DNS zone (see last section of my question) but it doesn't works. Do you mean to add such records in webs?

Comment: No, you should add parent DNS zone `contoso.com` in azure before you add subdomain in Azure. see [Delegate an Azure DNS subdomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to host subdomain `test.contoso.com` in Azure DNS, you should host your public domain `contoso.com` first in Azure DNS.

> To delegate an Azure DNS subdomain, you must first delegate your
>   public domain to Azure DNS. See [Delegate a domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns) for
>   instructions on how to configure your name servers for delegation.
>   Once your domain is delegated to your Azure DNS zone, you can delegate
>   your subdomain.

You could follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain) to delegate an Azure DNS subdomain.

1. Delegate your public domain `contoso.com` in Azure DNS.
2. Create a zone for your subdomain `test.contoso.com`.
3. Create a name server (NS) record for the subzone in your parent zone. For example, replace "engineering" with "test" in your scenario as below.
   [image]

Next, you could add A or CNAME record in the subzone `test.contoso.com` to point your website in Azure.

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks again for your help. I followed that guide step by step but it doesn't work since I fail the "Test the delegation" part (if I do `nslookup www.test.contoso.com`  I get `Non-existent domain`). Anyway I wrote to webs.com about this issue and they told me that at the moment it's not possible have the main web site hosted by them and a subdomain hosted by Azure. For this reason I think I can't solve this problem unless I create a new domain.

Comment: Hi, the above step is that you need to first host the main domain in Azure DNS then you could host subdomain in Azure DNS. I think you do not need to create a new domain if you could also host your root domain on Azure DNS and recreate DNS records in the DNS zone for the root domain. Otherwise, you need a new domain.